# changing alpha of pencil in drawing app

Tags: core-graphics, alpha-transparency

I am working on a drawing app in which the user chooses the alpha of the mark as well as the color and line width.  All works fine except....When I reduce the alpha and start to draw there are little darker dots every so often in the mark.  the faster you draw the father apart the dots are.  the dots are the size of the line width.  I will try to illustrate.

> /////////O/////////O////////O

The lines are the translucent mark whereas the Os are the dark dots.

Here is my code.

```
else if ([pencilString isEqualToString:@"blueViolet"]){

        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), w);  //w is the width of the line from a slider

        CGContextSetAlpha(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), a);  //a (alpha) is from a slider that adjust the value from 0.0f to 1.0f

        if (mode == DrawingModePen) {
            NSLog(@"drawing");
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);
        }
    }
```

Like I said the alpha does adjust but every so ofter it seems the mark has an alpha of 1.0.

Comment: This only happens in the lineCapRound and lineCapSquare  When I use LineCapButt there is no darker spots but when you go in an arc you get little spaces if moving quickly.

Comment: if I use `code`CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineJoinRound);`code`  I get a smooth rounded end line with no overlaps and no gaps but I do get a warning Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum CGLineJoin' to different enumeration type 'CGLineCap" (aka 'enum CGLineCap').  But if I use CGLineJoin I get the little gaps.  Can I just ignore the warning since it works the way I want?